# SQL syntax requiring FROM as part of SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a somewhat academic question, as I'm trying to get a better grip on SQL.

Why will this work:

```
SELECT id FROM nerds AS nerdnumber
```

but this won't?

```
SELECT nerds.id AS nerdnumber
```

To me, the FROM should not be necessary if my SELECT identifies the table already.

Comment: If the first one works, then the alias is being applied to the table, not the field.  I'm not sure about the as keyword though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what's actually happening behind the scenes is the engine takes your query and breaks it down and determines the actual instructions to be fired off to get you your data.

The syntax used (SELECT blah FROM ...) was developed and standardized (mostly) and that's what is used. The reason the FROM is required is... because it is :)

*COULD* the query parser be changed/written to work the way you propose? Don't see why not, but would create extra complexity to the parser. The SELECT, FROM, UPDATE, SET, and all the other keywords are important to let the parser find anchors for it to pull data from.

This is like... the quickest dirtiest reason, you can certainly go read about the development of the SQL standards and read about query optimization and parsing and read some really interesting and crazy stuff :)

Comment: Thanks. Daniel's answer was essentially saying the same thing but I have to pick one to accept. Sorry Daniel. threendib gets S/O-newbie bonus

Answer (score 3):

Including the table name in the select clause is for disambiguation when you're doing joins. The From clause specifies which tables the statement is accessing.

Comment: So you're saying the whole table name dot notation is really only used in a statement with `JOIN`'s?

Comment: The dot notation is never a bad idea.  However I don't think it's always worth the effort.

Comment: It is not meant ONLY for joins. It is required to disambiguated columns in joins though.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT id FROM nerds AS nerdnumber` and `SELECT nerds.id AS nerdnumber` are not equivalent queries. The first one aliases the table nerds as nerdsnumber the second tries to alias nerds.id as nerdersnumber. But I see your question.

Is what you are asking possible? Yes. Should it be done? Probably not. The reason a FROM clause is used is to define where your data is coming from. The fields in the select clause are used to determine what you use from your defined data set. This is a very easy to read and understand language (hence the original SEQL = structured english query language). Adding in the functionality you want will suddenly make it very hard to understand where query values are coming from. What if you have that table defined? What if you redefine that table name as an alias in your query?

It in the end just adds ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

**Both** will work if written properly.

If I understand your examples correctly, then in the first case you establish alias for a **table**,  and in the second - alias for a **field**.

So there's nothing wrong with `SELECT nerds.id AS nerdfield FROM nerdstable AS nerds;`